# Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I attempted to use Xamarin.Android.Support libraries version 25.3.1 but because of a bug I decided to downgrade back to my previous version 23.3.0. After Downgrading I am getting this error message below. whatever I tried, i cant get rid of it. I tried to delete all bin, obj, tmp etc folders. restarted VS2015, clean,rebuild...

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 
'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
    File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll'
       at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)
```

I found out a small change in my package.config file. All below 
targetFramework="monoandroid71" now. Before upgrade-downgrade, they were targetFramework="monoandroid70", I replaced them manulla but, it didnt help at all. How can I fix this problem?

```
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.ShortcutBadger" version="1.1.809" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
```

How my settings looks like
[image]

References:
[image]

UPDATE:
I have reinstalled all nugetpackages and succeed to run android project on 1 pc but interesting thing is same project is not running on another pc. It returns different but similar error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'myApp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'myApp.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String fileName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() myApp.Droid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I renamed the title because I had 2 following problem, they look similar indeed and both related to Android project only.

1. First one was complaining about support.Fragment which is available above 24.x.x versions but I was using 23.0.x. This was caused probably because of downgrading from 25.3.1 version. Whatever I tried, clean bin, obj, temp, rebuild didn't help. I used command `Update-Package –reinstall`to reinstall all NuGet packages in the solution. This helped on one of my PC. but on another PC of mine, I was getting 2nd error as in the question.
2. Error message below is indeed telling you that PCL project is not found under android. If you look at the Output window it will tell you that it is not found in Debug/Bin folder. When I look at my Bin folder, I saw that nothing was generated.

   The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'myApp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
   File name: 'myApp.dll'

It looks like this was caused by a NuGet package which is using .net standard 1.0. my PCL project was still using PCL profile. This is normally no problem if you have .Net Core 1.0 libraries as stated in the [article](https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms/) from Adam Pedley. How it was working on my other computer was because I had VS2017 installed. VS2017 installation has .Net Core automatically installed. But I was working on VS2015 and it requires separate installation.

I hope this helps anyone else is having the problem.

Comment: Beside the solution above, today I highly recommend to convert your .net standard 2.0, in order to avoid such problems because PCL has always different errors and effects your productivity.

Answer (score 6):

My problem is i updated xamarin form to 2.5.0.121934, 
Then, it shows Error "Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 
'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?"

So i downgrade my xamarin.form to 2.3.4.247, then it build successfully.

Comment: I found this link might helpful, in case you still want to update your xamarin forms to newest version https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/109615/could-not-load-assembly-xamarin-android-support-fragment-version-1-0-0-0

Answer (score 4):

The best option here is to uninstall ALL Xamarin and Android packages from your Xamarin.Android project. Then install Xamarin.Forms again, and it will add in the correct dependencies.

Alternatively, try downloading

```
Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment
```

Comment: I have already done it couple of times but It doesnt help unfortunately. Not sure what else I can do without creating a new project

Comment: When you uninstall the packages, are there any references left to these packages, if you expand the references section. Or any that show a warning sign?

Comment: they all look fine to me. I updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: Does it work if you target Android 7.0, in the Compile using Android Version: dropdown.

Comment: Try downloading the nuget package Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment

Comment: If you just install the Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, the dependency errors shift but do not go away. The Fragment appears to be of a higher version than the current Xamarin.Forms release. Anyway, it is a dependency maze and the error messages do not provide useful clues.

Comment: I'm seeing a mixture of targetFramework=monodroid70 / 71 and monodroid60 in the packages.config.

Comment: Hi Adam, unfortunately installing Fragment package wasnt solution but reinstalling everything partly solved my problem but it occured another similar error. please see my updated question.

Comment: @AdamPedley I have figured out actual problem. it looks like It caused a package using .net standard 1.0, My PCL project is not targeting .Net standard yet but using Profile 111. Interesting thing is the same package on same project works on another PC. how could this be possible? Am I having something not installed on other PC ?

Comment: .NET Standard 1.1 = Profile111 and .NET STandard 1.0 = Profile 259 (I think I go that right). They don't exactly equal but have the same API surface. Hence if the .net standard library is setup correctly, it will install on a Profile based PCL, provided the correct Standard #.

Comment: @AdamPedley actually you wrote an article about my problem :) https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms/ 
see my answer why i was having the problem. thanks to your article

Comment: In my case, I had to manually edit my .csproj and remove all the references to Xamarin.Forms.*

Answer (score 3):

Sadly the steps described here did not help me. But i got around to the cause.

First step of action is to determine what package wants to use the support.Fragment packages.

To do so set your MsBuild output to Diagnostics. (tools => options => projects and solutions => Build and run)

Then build, once the error has been reported find the support.fragment in the log.

In my case it was Acr.Userdialogs that tried to get the support.Fragment framework.

> Dependency "Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". (TaskId:415)
>
> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk.
>
> If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. (TaskId:415)
>
> Required by "Acr.UserDialogs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". (TaskId:415)

From here on it was a matter of downgrading the Acr.Userdialogs framework until this dependency was gone.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: as i wanted to update Acr.Dialogs on the matter i came across this : https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/373

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer, but since this type of dependency issue seems to creep up in multiple places, I finally found a way to at least see where the overlap is. See screen shot as follows. Just use the assember explorer "search" capability to locate the namespace in the error message. Then click on the namespace and it will pop-up with the duplicate entries and their dll locations.

[image: error message]
[image: Search the duplicate namespace in assembler explorer]

Comment: interesting information indeed. thanks for letting me know but i solved the problem with support library, now having different one. not sure if your solution can be applied for it?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might struggle with this, what did the trick for me was to discard all the changes in my `app/app/obj/Debug/app.Core.csprojFileListAbsolute.txt` and `app/app.Droid/Resources/Resource.Designer.cs` files, then deleting `bin` and `obj` folders' contents and finally rebuilding the project.